# /test.xlsx: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Tags: java, android, xls, xlsx

I am developing an android application where I need to pass some records to .xls or .xlsx file. I did everything to pass values from my java class to excel sheet in android. But when I run the application I am getting this error

```
/test.xlsx: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

I even gave permission in manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Can you help me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Because **you can't access the root** directory (/).

Comment: @DerGolem then how to access root directory?

Comment: **You can't access the root directory**. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to access the internal storage or the sd card. By the way, this permission**WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** also implicitly includes this one **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**. So, you don't need to specify both.